# Time management of a script asp

Tags: asp-classic

within a page ASP (classic) I have a function that connects to the server via XMLHTTP to google to get the time and distance between two points.
I noticed that sometimes my server makes this request very slowly sending the script out and blocking the page.
I would therefore ask you.
If I change the attached script to say
if the execution time exceeds five seconds then stops the script

```
function GooDistInd(origine,destintario)

Set objxml = Nothing


     ' Dichiaro le variabili che mi servono nello script
        Dim file, objXmlHttp, objXmlDom, distanza, cognome, i


        'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=40.7143528,-74.0059731&destination=40.7035458,-74.21607971&sensor=false
         file = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="& origine &"destination="&destintario &"&sensor=false"

        Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            objXmlHttp.Open "GET", file, False
            objXmlHttp.Send


        Set objXmlDom = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
            objXmlDom.async = False
            objXmlDom.loadXML(objXmlHttp.responseText)


        Set tempo = objXmlDom.getElementsByTagName("leg/distance/value")


        i = 0


        For i = 0 To tempo.length - 1



             distanza=tempo(i).Text
             exit for
        Next



        GooDistInd =distanza


 end function
```

Comment: If you want to stop the script completely you could use Server.ScriptTimeout = 5. You could also use the timeut property of the Microsoft.XMLHTTP object and set it to 5000 ms. In this case you could work with on error resume next and check if an error occurred, so you could give back a significant error message to you users.

Comment: @schudel: I would make that an answer if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the script completely you could use

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 5
```

You could also use the timeut property of the Microsoft.XMLHTTP object and set it to 5000 ms. In this case you could work with on error resume next and check if an error occurred, so you could give back a significant error message to you users